Issues with Interaction Terms in slopes() Function from marginaleffects
I am using the marginaleffects package in R to calculate marginal effects from a multinomial logistic regression model (MNL) that includes an interaction term. I want to calculate the Marginal Effects at the Mean (MEM) for each term in the MNL; the marginaleffects documentation refers me to the slopes function with the argument newdata = means. My MNL contains an interaction term, and the slopes function does not seem to be recognized correctly. Here’s a summary of my problem and what I’ve tried:
My model includes both main effects and an interaction term:
modelCO <- multinom(choice ~ risk + crop_loss + tech_loss + Policy + crop_loss:tech_loss, data = risk_simple_CO)

The interaction term on crop_loss and tech_loss is correctly specified in the model
modelCO[["coefnames"]]
[1] "(Intercept)"         "risk"                "crop_loss"          
[4] "tech_loss"           "Policy"              "crop_loss:tech_loss"


Issue with slopes Function
When I try to calculate the MEM using the slopes() function with newdata = "means", I receive a warning that the interaction term is not found:
memCO <- slopes(modelCO, newdata = "means", variables = c("risk", "crop_loss", "tech_loss", "Policy", "crop_loss:tech_loss"))

Warning message:
These variables were not found: crop_loss:tech_loss. Try specifying the
  `newdata` argument explicitly and make sure the missing variable is
  included.


I tried manually created the newdata data frame to create the interaction term
`meansCO <- risk_simple_CO %>%
  summarize(
    risk = mean(risk, na.rm = TRUE),
    crop_loss = mean(crop_loss, na.rm = TRUE),
    tech_loss = mean(tech_loss, na.rm = TRUE),
    Policy = mean(Policy, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
meansCO <- meansCO %>%
  mutate(`crop_loss:tech_loss` = crop_loss * tech_loss)
newdata_manual <- as.data.frame(meansCO)
memCO <- slopes(modelCO, newdata = newdata_manual, variables = c("risk", "crop_loss", "tech_loss", "Policy", "crop_loss:tech_loss"))`

However, I still encountered issues with the interaction term not being correctly evaluated. Manually defining newdata does change the MEM estimate from slopes, though.
Why does the slopes function not handle the interaction term correctly when using newdata = "means"?
How can I correctly specify the newdata argument to ensure the interaction term is included and properly evaluated?

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

You should never specify an interaction like crop_loss:tech_loss in any of the arguments of any of the functions in the marginaleffects package.
Please read the detailed tutorials on the marginaleffects website, especially the Get Started and the Slopes pages. These tutorials do a much better job of explaining this than I can in a few words on StackOverflow. https://marginaleffects.com
Now let's review the argument definitions documented in the help files:
First, slopes() computes the partial derivative of the outcome with respect to a variable of interest. In a multinomial logit model, this can be interpreted as "the effect of increasing variable X by a small amount on the probability that Y is at a given level". There will be one estimate per level, per row of the "grid" (dataset).
Second, the variables argument determines what is the "independent" or "explanatory" variable of interest. This is the variable with respect to which we are taking the slope. It makes little sense to specify crop_loss:tech_loss here. This multiplicative term will change automatically whenever one of the two variables changes. You don't need to (and shouldn't) specify it explicitly. Just set variables to your actual explanatory variable of interest.
Third, the newdata argument fixes the values of all other covariates. If you set newdata="mean", then all covariates will be set to their means when computing slopes. The interaction is always taken into account, because it is part of the model. This argument just determines where in the covariate space you want to evaluate the slope.
So you have three main options.
A) The effect of increasing crop_loss by a small amount on the outcome, holding all covariates at their mean:
slopes(model, variables = "crop_loss", newdata = "mean")

B) The effect of increasing tech_loss by a small amount on the outcome, holding all covariates at their mean:
slopes(model, variables = "tech_loss", newdata = "mean")

C) The effect of increasing tech_loss by a small amount on the outcome, holding tech_loss at specified values, and all other covariates at their mean:
slopes(model, 
    variables = "tech_loss", 
    newdata = datagrid(crop_loss = c(2, 5)))

If you are not interested in the "slope", and instead want to answer a question like:

What happens to the predicted outcome if tech_loss increases by 1 standard deviation?

You can use the comparisons() function documented here: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/comparisons.html
